# Binding to object in WinRT

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm looking for a way to achieve the following in a Windows 8 app:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=x}" />
```

The `TextBlock` is inside a `DataTemplate` for `ItemTemplate` of a `ListView`, but for some reason, Binding to . doesn’t seem to work in WinRT (the binding error says: `Error: BindingExpression path error: '.' property not found`), while the same thing works on WPF/Silverlight/Windows Phone.

I’m trying to do this, because I want to pass the entire bound object (not just a single property) to a converter to output a string that relies on multiple values of the object.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to expose a property on the object that returns the string you need and then bind to that property?

Comment: @JustinSkiles, I'd rather not do that, as I would like to keep my model as clean as possible and do the actual string formatting in a Converter (where it should be done in my opinion). I just find it very strange that `{Binding .}` doesn't work in XAML on WinRT, while it works fine on WPF/Silverlight/Windows Phone.

Comment: Could u post the code for your binding object?

Comment: @Bitsian, I could, but I don't really see the point as it's just a class with a couple of properties. Could you elaborate on how that would help? (Finding alternatives to {Binding .} most likely?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following to bind the whole object.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}" />
```

If you don't specify the path (explicitly or implicitly) it will bind to the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you are using a converter, i think this would be more appropriate

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding propertName, Converter={StaticResource ConverterKey}}" />
```

You need to reference the converter you wrote as well

```
<converter:ConverterClass x:Key="ConverterKey" Component="YourConverter" />
```

Comment: Apologies for not providing a complete snippet initially, I've updated my question. The issue is that I don't want to bind against one particular property, but against the entire object, so I can use multiple properties in the converter to generate the output.